# insert null character using tamper data

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, http, headers, tampering

Using the firefox extension tamper data (for modifing http requests that firefox makes) how do I insert a null character into a post field? I can enter normal characters, but binary characters in it are not urlencoded and are shown as is, so how do I enter the null character into a field? If you know of a firefox extension like tamper data that I can do this or a way to do this using tamper data please post.

Answer (score 1):

Would `%00` work?

---

I used to use **[burp proxy](http://portswigger.net/proxy/)** - it's a standalone Java program acting as a HTTP proxy, so can be used for anything.

Comment: I can confirm that %00 works with Tamper Data. One exception is if your form has enctype="multipart/form-data". In that case, I'm not sure how you insert a null character in the Tamper Data request.